# Why is the LOL client resetting the download?

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

I was trying to install LOL. I got to the screen that allows you to log in, the thing is, the percentage bar goes back to 0%. Many people say that it goes down but keeps downloading whats missing. But it doesn't, it goes all the way down to 13GB when it left at 5GB , I have been trying to download this for three days now and it keeps going on, I do not have any idea how to fix it.

Comment: Is it anything to do with your internet?

Comment: i dont know, it goes to scanning the files and then resets, and makes my download speed go down

Comment: Then it's not that it isn't downloading. It gets errors (likely due to internet issues), and whenever it reconnects it rescans the files.

Comment: then why does it start from the beginning if it scans what it already downloaded

Comment: i just checked, it seems that every time it restarts it erases the whole temp patching file so its gonna be an infinite loop

Comment: Maybe try cancelling the download and restarting your network + computer and see if it happens again?

Comment: still not solved

Comment: @madboi download the lol repair tool, I think it has an option to "reinstall" a problematic installation. It might help

Answer (score 1):

Restart of update download may occur when is error thrown while downloading updates.

Next reason shlould be:

- LoL client has no rights to the folder
- LoL client has bug (Not very often to have bug in updater...)
- LoL client has no rights thru firewall
- LoL client is being blocked by another programs like antiviruses etc
- When your PC is low on memory (This should stop updates, but i saw never their code...)
- LoL client has some connection drops
- Some kind of problem IO in your cpu (practically insane)